# form validation using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I have a form

```
<form name="formName">
 <table>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="validate" required/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="validate()">save</button>
```

as you can see, the button is outside the form.. I want to validate the form when I click the button into $scope.validate();

the question is, how can I achieve that using angularjs ?

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Take a look at the awesome `ngMessages` directive introduced in 1.3 for form validations: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html

Comment: nope but angularjs is ignoring my validation actually... could you help me? @thomasbabuj

Comment: First I would rather delegate validations into directives (the controller should be used only to expose data to bind and call the services to retrieve data), if you want more info about this I can send you some links an sample (you play with the property form isValid in order to enable/disable a submit button). About the validate not being called, could you please post a plunkr or jsfiddle so we can pinpoint where is the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I don't have them.. all I have is the mock up above.. what I want is just validation when I clicked the button and send it to the validate() function @Braulio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if button is in or outside the form, the validation is performed always when any of the proprties of the  model changes. So the only problem that remains is when to display error message.

btw required is from HTML5 ng-required is the attribute you should use.

The code below displays error message when any of the properties changes

```
<div ng-app="mod">
<div ng-controller='MCtrl'>
    <form name="formName" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="prop" ng-model="model.property" ng-required="true" />
                    <span ng-show="formName.prop.$error.required">Required</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="validate(formName)">save</button>
</div>
```

```
mod.controller('MCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = { property : ''};

    $scope.validate = function(form){
        alert(form.$valid);
    }

});
```

If youd like to display the errors only when the form is submitted you add one variable to track it like it the code below (note additional variable in ng-show="formName.prop.$error.required && submitted"

```
<div ng-app="mod">
<div ng-controller='MCtrl'>
    <form name="formName" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="prop" ng-model="model.property" ng-required="true" />
                    <span ng-show="formName.prop.$error.required && submitted">Required</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="validate(formName)">save</button>
</div>
```

```
mod.controller('MCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = { property : ''};
    $scope.submitted = false;

    $scope.validate = function(form){
        $scope.submitted = true;
        alert(form.$valid);
    }

});
```

Comment: what you explained to me is very clear.. thank you so much.. it works like magic ! :)